# Remove a directory with all of its contents using find under unix

Tags: bash, find

I am writing a ShellScript that deletes every found.??? folders with its contents.
I wrote this:

```
find $DRIVE -name 'found.???' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

It does what I want, but gives this error:

```
find: „/media/.../found.000”: No such file or directory
find: „/media/.../found.001”: No such file or directory
```

What can I do with this?
Thanks!

Comment: What OS/distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04
#!/bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an issue. `find` is going to pre-process some results and when it tries to delete some directories which have already been deleted, you will get the stderr.

You can either ignore the error messages, use `-depth` to make it traverse in DFS, or force it to `-prune` the directories. i.e.

```
find "$DRIVE" -mindepth 1 -depth -name 'found.???' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

or

```
find "$DRIVE" -mindepth 1 -name 'found.???' -type d -prune -exec rm -r {} \;
```

*Note, `mindepth 1` is important so you don't accidentally delete `"$DRIVE"`*

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that you're trying to populate a FAT-based fs. Try presenting the real case of those filenames instead:

```
find "$DRIVE" -name 'FOUND.???' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

And quote your variable too.