# Unix 'find' without descending into matched directories

Tags: unix, find

I was trying to remove all git files from a repository with this:

```
find . -name ".git*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

However, `rm` warns that files could not be deleted (because their parent directory has already been deleted).

Is there a way to get `find` to stop recursing when it finds a matching directory?

E.g. `find...`

```
/.gitmodules
/.git/stuff
/.git/.gitfile
```

... produces

```
/.gitmodules
/.git
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a directory with all of its contents using find under unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723499/remove-a-directory-with-all-of-its-contents-using-find-under-unix)

Comment: So you can do something like `find -type d -name ".git*" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-depth`:

```
find . -depth -name ".git*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This would allow you to process the files or subdirectories first before their parent directories.