# Prevent Unix "find" command from recursing into matched directories

Tags: git, bash, unix, recursion, find

Consider the following command to find and update all git repos in a particular directory:

```
find . -type d -name .git | while read src_dir; do
    my_git_update "${1}";
done;
```

Assume that a repo cannot contain other repos, so there is no point in going deeper into that directory. I am not using sub-modules and such, so nested cases don't count for this question. So in general...

**Is there a way to tell `find` to stop recursing into a directory once a match is found?**

Based on my searches, the answer may lie with `-prune`, but I can't figure out exactly how to use it in my case.

---

[Unix 'find' without descending into matched directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930778/) is ***not*** a duplicate, despite the title. It focuses on deletion of sub-directories - that solution is not applicable here.

Comment: If you cannot make find do exactly what you want, a "look recursively for .git until found" is not hard to write in Perl as a pseudo-oneliner.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen True, and I typically use ruby or perl scripts. This question leans more towards curiosity, with hints of portability and minimalism :)

Comment: As far as I can remember the original find did not support what you need here, so if you find a magic incantation you might find it only works on some systems and not all.   For instance OS X is more BSD'ish and Linux is GNU'ish so it is not uncommon to see that advanced scripts require extra thought to work on all systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the answer is `-prune`:

> This primary always evaluates to true.  It causes find to not
>                descend into the current file.  Note, the `-prune` primary has no
>                effect if the `-d` option was specified.

(`-d` and `-depth` are essentially synonymous in this particular `find`).

Compare with `-print`:

> This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of
>                the current file to standard output.

This means you use them in the same way: after testing previous conditions and deciding that you are at a directory that should not be recursively traveled, simply `-prune` it to move on to the next directory.  (The reason `-d` renders it ineffective is that with `-d`, the `find` code has already run everything within the directory, so the pruning step of moving on, is what is about to happen anyway.)

Comment: I'm not too clear on the actual syntax. Where exactly do I put the `-prune` option in my example? Would it work when I'm piping to another command as shown or do I have to use `-exec` somehow?

Comment: Put it the same place you'd put `-print`.  For instance, suppose you want to find items (dirs/files) that have not been modified in 14 days: `find <path> -mtime +14 -print`.  Suppose further that after printing, if it's a directory you want to skip any sub-directories within that directory: add `-prune` before or after `-print` (`-prune` effectively clears the flag that says "this is a directory so find must recurse into it", so it's harmless on plain files).

Comment: For a more interesting example, suppose you want to find all files whose name matches `*.updateme` *unless* they're inside a directory named `*.pruneme`.  Then: `find . ( -type d -name '*.pruneme' -prune ) -o ( -name '*.updateme' -print )` would suffice.  Here we need the `-o` ("or") operator since `-name '*.pruneme'` fails on things named `*.updateme`.  Technically the parens are not required since the syntax says that unparenthesized "and" operations must be bound more tightly than "or" operations (and `-a` = "and" is implied if there is no explicit operator).